# Stacktable plugin is cloning only one table

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I have three tables on my webpage. I want it to be responsive so, I have used [Stacktable.js](http://johnpolacek.github.io/stacktable.js/) to make it responsive, but stacktable.js is cloning only one table, I want all tables to be cloned and responsive.

I am hitting stacktable plugin with this code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tablecaption').stacktable();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Technically you shouldn't be using the #tablecaption ID on more than one element. IDs should be unique. Use classes for non-unique identifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about calling method on each element?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("table#tablecaption").each(function(){
      $(this).stacktable();
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: It still cloning only one table.

Comment: Does every table got id="tablecaption"?

Comment: ya, every table has this id="tablecaption".

Comment: Can you reproduce situation on jsfiddle?

Comment: I've fixed the answer. It seems that jquery didn't select all elements unless I changed the selector to `table#tablecaption`